# Return json enconde associative array only one item

Tags: php, arrays, json, associative-array

I have a `$variable = array(...);`

And I need print it a JSON response like this

```
{
  info: {
    "foo": true,
    "bar": "lion"
  },
  data: [
    {"id": 123,
     "name": "foo",
     "baz": {  "some":1,
               "data":true
             }
    },
    {"id": 321,
     "name": "bar",
     "baz": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

So, the problem is with `response["data"][1]["baz"]`

Sometimes, this variable can by a empty array `{}` but when I uses `json_encode` return this as no-associative array `[]`

> I need this variable as associative array

but if in PHP we put

```
echo json_encode($variable,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Return this

```
{
  info: {
    "foo": true,
    "bar": "lion"
  },
  data: {
    0: {"id": 123,
        "name": "foo",
        "baz": {  "some":1,
                  "data":true
                }
    },
    1: {"id": 321,
        "name": "bar",
        "baz": {}
       }
  ]
}
```

and `response["data"]` **must** be a no-associative array

thus,

- return `baz` as an associative array `{}` (even if empty, here the problem).
- return `data` always as no-associative array `[]`.

---

`response["data"]` must be a list because is read by a external library in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the property in question an [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) rather than a built-in array, it will be serialized as an object regardless if it's empty.

```
# Converting the existing array, which may be empty, to an ArrayObject
$baz = new ArrayObject($baz);

# Or create a new ArrayObject
$baz = new ArrayObject();
$baz['a'] = 'b';
```

Alternatively you could use the [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php) class in those cases when the array is empty. This will be serialized as an empty object (`{}`).

```
if (empty($baz)) {
    $baz = new stdClass();
}
```

Comment: no works, I try with `new ArrayObject()` and `new stdClass()`

Comment: Using those, you can remove JSON_FORCE_OBJECT.

Comment: I try without `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`, `baz` is still `[]`

Comment: My bad, its ok, thanks, `$row_['d'] = $row_['d'] === null ? new ArrayObject() : $row_['d'];`, works perfect